# Merge and manipulate two df in python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a data which looks like below
[image]

```
data1 = {'View name': ['v1', 'v3'],
         'view desc': ['abc', 'fgt'],
         'Reason for Diff': ['Duplicate row', 'View not found']}

data2 = {'View name': ['v1', 'v1', 'v2'],
         'view Desc': ['abc', 'xyz', 'bnm']}
```

want to compare df1 and df2 and make sure except for the last occurrences (V1) every other row of it should be a duplicate row. below code works only for View not found, but not for Duplicate row.

```
    def compare_columns_vd(row):
        if row['View Name'] not in selected_cols_df1['View Name'].astype(str).values:
            return 'View Not Found'   
        return 'NA'
    
    view_desc_diff_df['Reason for Diff'] = view_desc_diff_df.apply(compare_columns_vd, axis=1)

    if 'NA' in view_desc_diff_df['Reason for Diff'].values:
        found_values = set(view_desc_df['View Description'])

        status_list = []

        for idx, row in vd_df_ip.iterrows():
            value = row['View Description']
            status = 'NA' if value in found_values else 'Duplicate Row'
            status_list.append(status)

        view_desc_diff_df['Reason for Diff'] = status_list
        
        #print(view_desc_df['status'])
        if len(status_list) == len(view_desc_df):
            view_desc_df['status'] = status_list
        else:
            print("Length of status_list does not match the length of view_desc_df")

        #view_desc_diff_df['Reason for Diff'] = view_desc_df['status']
        view_desc_diff_df.loc[view_desc_diff_df['Reason for Diff'] == 'NA', 'Reason for Diff'] = view_desc_df['status']
```

Comment: please provide your example data as either an actual table in text (click on the interrogation point on top right of edit field), or in python code, this makes it it much easier for usto write and test an answer

Comment: i have done. please check now

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

- Use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `how` parameter set to `"left"` and activating the `indicator` option.
- Select the `indicator` column, by default called `"_merge"`, from the result and apply [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to change the potential outcomes `"both"` (a row occurs in both `dfs`) and `"left_only"` (a row only occurs in the first `df`) into your desired strings and assign as a new column.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'View name': ['v1', 'v3'],
         'view desc': ['abc', 'fgt']} # removing the column we want to add!

data2 = {'View name': ['v1', 'v1', 'v2'],
         'view Desc': ['abc', 'xyz', 'bnm']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# make life easier by providing both `dfs` with the same column names, e.g.
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'view Desc': 'view desc'})
# or:
df2.columns = df1.columns

# dict for mapping `indicator` values
map_dict = {'both': 'Duplicate row',
            'left_only': 'View not found'}

df1['Reason for Diff'] = (df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True)
                          ['_merge'].map(map_dict))

df1

  View name view desc Reason for Diff
0        v1       abc   Duplicate row
1        v3       fgt  View not found
```